# Finding out sytem architecture using Java

Tags: java, architecture, 64-bit

I'm trying to find out the system architecture using Java and I've tried out:

```
operatingSystemMXBean.getArch()
```

and

```
String sys1=System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
```

but I get `amd64` when I'm using an Intel 64 bit processor.

I've read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) on Wiki to clear up my concepts. Am I missing something? Also, how can I get the actual System architecture using Java so that I get an output saying Intel 64?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intel 64-Bit-Processors use the amd-architecture. That's why many systems note that as amd64, the alternative synonym is x64 or x86-64 for both.

Comment: Yep. Intel tried to get the 64-bit moniker with its Itanium architecture (IA-64) but it never took off, mainly because AMD's 64 bit offerings were way cheaper than what Intel could provide at the time.

Answer (score 2):

the AMD64 bit was patented by AMD, and Intel licenses their AMD64 architecture. Thus, you get AMD64 as architecture on an Intel CPU.

Still,

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"));
```

will give you more CPU info, some of which is whether it is an Intel or AMD cpu!

Comment: On which operating system is PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER usually set?

Comment: It is at least on Windows, but I should admit that I don't know about other OSes.

Comment: It is not standard on Mac OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider this package:
[Sigar (`org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo`)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/), You can find the `javadoc` [here](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/CpuInfo.html)

Not sure, it might be an overkill, but it supposed to give you all the information you need about your system (including the CPU information in the class above)

This package is free under the Apache License 2.0.

Comment: @OfirFarchy- Thanks but for just one command, I don't really want to use Sigar.